# JS is not loading in localhost

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am working on this stylish menu. However, I do not know why it is not working in localhost. It was working perfectly fine using this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/NBabKR). But when I transferred the code to my localhost, it's suddenly not working. I hope someone can help me figure out why it is not loading. Please see image below of my current output.
(UPDATED---from this image output:
[image]

This is what i am seeing now. And seeing as it was working on your end, i believe it's due to the placement of my external codes. the animation works a little(when hovered) but it seems to me that it is not retrieving the content of the project category. Is the due to the placement of my declarations? or something else?
[image]

This is the code i'm using

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Stylish Menu</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<h2>Our Brands</h2>

<div id="projectsApp">

  <div class="projects" :id="project.ID" v-for="project in projects" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + project.bImage + ')' }" v-on:click="selectProjects(project.ID)">
    <h3 class="beforeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h3>
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="fadeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p class="backArrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  </div>

  <div class="selectedArea">
    <h1 :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + highlightedContent.bImage + ')' }"><span>{{ highlightedContent.category }}</span></h1>
    <div v-html="highlightedContent.copy" class="copyArea fadeIn"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #090909; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #976734;
  height: 5px; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; }

#projectsApp {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; }

.projects {
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 1% 10px 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease, opacity 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease, opacity 0.1s; }
  .projects.shrunk {
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease; }
  .projects.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; }
  .projects .backArrow {
    display: none; }
  .projects.midTransition {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0px; }
  .projects.openedProject {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 100; }
    .projects.openedProject .backArrow {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      float: left;
      font-size: 30pt;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px;
      top: 45%;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
    .projects.openedProject .info {
      background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.9) !important;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
    .projects.openedProject:hover .info {
      background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.7) !important; }
    .projects.openedProject:hover .backArrow {
      transform: scale(1.2); }
  .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
    width: 48%; }
  .projects .beforeTitle {
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45%;
    margin: 0px 5% 0px 5%; }
  .projects.openedProject .beforeTitle, .projects.openedProject h1, .projects.openedProject hr {
    display: none; }
  .projects.openedProject .info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 000px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(1, 154, 109, 0.8); }
  .projects:hover .beforeTitle, .projects.midTransition .beforeTitle {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  .projects:hover .info, .projects.midTransition .info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 000px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(116, 28, 84, 0.8); }
    .projects:hover .info h1, .projects.midTransition .info h1 {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0%, 0);
      -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0); }
    .projects:hover .info hr, .projects.midTransition .info hr {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0px 15% 0px 15%;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 1; }
  .projects .info {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(1, 154, 109, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease, opacity 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease, opacity 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; }
    .projects .info .fadeTitle {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 12pt;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0px;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
      top: 45%;
      transform: translate(0%, -25px);
      -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -25px);
      transition-delay: 0.4s;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s; }
    .projects .info hr {
      outline: none;
      height: 3px;
      border: 0px;
      float: left;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 2px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -1px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 53%;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s; }

.selectedArea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 00%;
  max-height: 0px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.0s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.0s ease; }
  .selectedArea.opened {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100000%; }
    .selectedArea.opened .copyArea.fadeIn, .selectedArea.opened h1 span, .selectedArea.opened h1 {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0%);
      transform: translate(0px, 0%); }
  .selectedArea:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: red;
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rrgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
    /* Standard syntax */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; }
  .selectedArea h1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 80px 5px 80px 5px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
    .selectedArea h1 span {
      background: #fff;
      padding: 10px 80px 10px 80px;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);
      transform: translate(0%, -100%);
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease; }
  .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn {
    width: 880px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 100%);
    transform: translate(0%, 100%);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s; }
    .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn p {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 12pt;
      line-height: 24pt;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-weight: 100;
      color: #2a2a2a; }

.noTransition {
  transition: all 0.0s ease !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.0s ease !important;
  transition-delay: 0.0s !important;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.0s !important; }

@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  .projects {
    width: 48%; }
    .projects hr {
      top: 60% !important; }
    .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
      width: 48%; }
      .projects:nth-child(1) hr, .projects:nth-child(2) hr {
        top: 53% !important; }

  .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    left: 0%; }
  .selectedArea h1 {
    font-size: 20pt; }
    .selectedArea h1 span {
      padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .projects {
    width: 98% !important; }
    .projects hr {
      top: 55% !important; }
    .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
      width: 48%; }
      .projects:nth-child(1) hr, .projects:nth-child(2) hr {
        top: 55% !important; } }
```

**main.js**

```
var isSelected = false;
const myProjects = [
  {
    ID: "-balmainParis",
    category: "Balmain Paris",
    bImage: "http://twofeetmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/web-designer.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-atkinsonsLondon",
    category: "Atkinsons London",
    bImage:
      "https://i1.wp.com/diymarketers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Graphic-designer-at-work.-Color-samples-000089125041_Small.jpg?fit=800%2C533",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-appellesApothecary",
    category: "Appelles Apothecary",
    bImage:
      "https://agc.creativelive.com/agc/pages/channel-hero/Photo_Hero_1600x900.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-biologySmart",
    category: "Biology Smart Skincare",
    bImage:
      "https://i0.wp.com/webdesignledger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/7-logo-sketches.jpg?w=970",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-soak",
    category: "Soak",
    bImage: "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1644197/images/o-EMAIL-facebook.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-kevinMurphy",
    category: "Kevin Murphy",
    bImage:
      "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-urbanSkincare",
    category: "Urban Skincare Co.",
    bImage:
      "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-zambeli",
    category: "Zambeli",
    bImage:
      "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  },
  {
    ID: "-embrace",
    category: "Embrace",
    bImage:
      "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
  }
];

var theHighlightedContent = { ID: "", category: "", bImage: "", copy: "" };
var selectedProject;
var scrollBackTo;

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#projectsApp",
  data() {
    return {
      projects: myProjects,
      highlightedContent: theHighlightedContent
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectProjects: function(thisId) {
      var self = "#" + thisId;
      if ($(self).hasClass("openedProject")) {
        isSelected = false;

        if($(self).hasClass('noTransition')){
          var timeoutA = 0;
          var timeoutB = 0;
          var timeoutC = 0;
        }else{
          var timeoutA = 800;
          var timeoutB = 1200;
          var timeoutC = 1600;
        }



        $(self).addClass("midTransition");
        $(self).removeClass("openedProject");




        setTimeout(function() {

          $(self).removeClass("midTransition");
          $(".selectedArea").removeClass("opened");

        }, timeoutA);

       setTimeout(function() {
         $("#projectsApp .projects").removeClass("hidden");
         $("#projectsApp .projects").removeClass("shrunk");
          }, timeoutB);
        setTimeout(function() {
        // window.scrollTo(0, scrollBackTo);
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollBackTo}, 500);
          $(self).addClass('noTransition');
          }, timeoutC);

      } else {
        isSelected = true;
        scrollBackTo = $(self).offset().top;

        if($(self).hasClass('noTransition')){
          $(".selectedArea").addClass("noTransition");
          $(".copyArea.fadeIn").addClass("noTransition");
          var timeoutD = 0;
        }else{
           $(".selectedArea").removeClass("noTransition");
          $(".copyArea.fadeIn").removeClass("noTransition");
          var timeoutD = 800;
        }

        $(self).addClass("midTransition");
        $("#projectsApp .projects").addClass("hidden");
        $(self).removeClass("hidden");

        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".selectedArea").addClass("opened");
          $(self).addClass("openedProject");
          $(self).removeClass("midTransition");
          $("#projectsApp .projects").addClass("shrunk");

          $(self).removeClass("shrunk");

          window.scrollTo(0, 0);


        }, timeoutD);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < this.projects.length; i++) {
        if (thisId == this.projects[i].ID) {
          this.highlightedContent = this.projects[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeProjectDivs();
  // resizeProjectDivs();
});
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on("resize", function(e) {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    if (isSelected == false) {
      resizeProjectDivs();
    }
  }, 250);
});

function resizeProjectDivs() {
  var midRange = false;
  var smallRange = false;
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  if (winWidth < 920 && 620 < winWidth) {
    midRange = true;
  }
  if (winWidth < 720) {
    smallRange = true;
  }
  var i = 0;

  $("#projectsApp .projects").each(function() {
    var pWidth = $(this).width();
    var pHeight;
    if (i < 2) {
      pHeight = pWidth;
    } else {
      if (midRange == true) {
        pHeight = pWidth * 0.5;
      } else if (smallRange == true) {
        pHeight = pWidth;
      } else {
        pHeight = pWidth * 1.5;
      }
    }
    $(this).css("height", pHeight + "px");
    i++;
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you run a http server on localhost?

Comment: What does console say?

Comment: browser **developer** tools console is your development pal - refer to it, let it tell you what you've done wrong

Comment: how do i do that? Im currently using sublimetext for coding and xammp server

Comment: @UmaruHime F12 and see the console?

Comment: Do you have internet connection Just make sure,You are using cdn links to access jquery and vue

Comment: And try using those script tags in head tag itself it may make difference.Try to inspect your browser's console ,It can pin point the issue.

Comment: I hope you know what the "layout trashing" is. You introduced it in your code. And mixing the jQuery with Vue in the way you do will never work.

Comment: Hi. Yes @PratheeshNambi I have connections.I have inserted it on the head tag and shows a little difference but it still doesn't work. However, I am not familiar with the use of browser's console.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky I was only using code templates found on codepen and tried to apply it to my own. I am pretty sure it is working fine. I just wanted to know why the very animation is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried and it's working perfectly.
Try with below code 
Import CSS and JS properly to your html file.

You need to import below vue js file in your local html file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
         * {
         box-sizing: border-box !important;
         font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
         ::-webkit-scrollbar {
         width: 12px !important;
         height: 10px;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         border-top: 1px solid #090909; }
         ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         background-color: #976734;
         height: 5px; }
         html, body {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0; }
         h2 {
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-weight: 100;
         letter-spacing: 50px;
         float: left;
         text-align: center;
         width: 100%; }
         #projectsApp {
         width: 100%;
         float: left; }
         .projects {
         width: 23%;
         float: left;
         min-height: 50px;
         height: 50px;
         position: relative;
         background-size: cover;
         background-position: center;
         cursor: pointer;
         margin: 10px 1% 10px 1%;
         overflow: hidden;
         transition: all 0.5s ease, opacity 0.1s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease, opacity 0.1s; }
         .projects.shrunk {
         pointer-events: none;
         height: 0px !important;
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 0px !important;
         padding: 0px;
         transition: all 0.9s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease; }
         .projects.hidden {
         opacity: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         transition: all 1s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; }
         .projects .backArrow {
         display: none; }
         .projects.midTransition {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-height: 100% !important;
         position: fixed;
         z-index: 100;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         right: 0;
         margin: 0px; }
         .projects.openedProject {
         width: 40px !important;
         height: 100% !important;
         min-height: 100%;
         position: fixed;
         margin: 0px;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         z-index: 100; }
         .projects.openedProject .backArrow {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         float: left;
         font-size: 30pt;
         color: #fff;
         width: 100%;
         float: left;
         text-align: center;
         margin: 0px;
         top: 45%;
         transition: all 0.2s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
         .projects.openedProject .info {
         background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.9) !important;
         transition: all 0.2s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
         .projects.openedProject:hover .info {
         background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.7) !important; }
         .projects.openedProject:hover .backArrow {
         transform: scale(1.2); }
         .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
         width: 48%; }
         .projects .beforeTitle {
         float: left;
         opacity: 1;
         background: #fff;
         padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
         font-weight: 100;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         position: absolute;
         width: 90%;
         text-align: center;
         top: 45%;
         margin: 0px 5% 0px 5%; }
         .projects.openedProject .beforeTitle, .projects.openedProject h1, .projects.openedProject hr {
         display: none; }
         .projects.openedProject .info {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         margin-top: 0;
         margin-left: 0px;
         border-radius: 000px;
         opacity: 1;
         background: rgba(1, 154, 109, 0.8); }
         .projects:hover .beforeTitle, .projects.midTransition .beforeTitle {
         opacity: 0;
         transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; }
         .projects:hover .info, .projects.midTransition .info {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         margin-top: 0;
         margin-left: 0px;
         border-radius: 000px;
         opacity: 1;
         background: rgba(116, 28, 84, 0.8); }
         .projects:hover .info h1, .projects.midTransition .info h1 {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: translate(0%, 0);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0); }
         .projects:hover .info hr, .projects.midTransition .info hr {
         width: 70%;
         margin: 0px 15% 0px 15%;
         left: 0px;
         opacity: 1; }
         .projects .info {
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
         left: 50%;
         top: 50%;
         margin-left: -25px;
         margin-top: -25px;
         float: left;
         opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         background: rgba(1, 154, 109, 0);
         overflow: hidden;
         transition: all 0.2s ease, opacity 0.1s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease, opacity 0.1s;
         transition-delay: 0.1s;
         -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; }
         .projects .info .fadeTitle {
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         color: #fff;
         font-weight: 100;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: 12pt;
         text-align: center;
         letter-spacing: 5px;
         position: absolute;
         margin: 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         transition: all 0.3s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
         padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
         top: 45%;
         transform: translate(0%, -25px);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -25px);
         transition-delay: 0.4s;
         -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s; }
         .projects .info hr {
         outline: none;
         height: 3px;
         border: 0px;
         float: left;
         background-color: #fff;
         width: 2px;
         left: 50%;
         margin-left: -1px;
         opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         top: 53%;
         transition: all 0.4s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
         transition-delay: 0.5s;
         -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s; }
         .selectedArea {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 00%;
         max-height: 0px;
         float: left;
         background: #fff;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 10;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
         opacity: 0;
         pointer-events: none;
         overflow: hidden;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         transition: all 0.0s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.0s ease; }
         .selectedArea.opened {
         opacity: 1;
         pointer-events: all;
         min-height: 100%;
         max-height: 100000%; }
         .selectedArea.opened .copyArea.fadeIn, .selectedArea.opened h1 span, .selectedArea.opened h1 {
         opacity: 1;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0%);
         transform: translate(0px, 0%); }
         .selectedArea:after {
         content: '';
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         background: red;
         /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
         /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
         background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
         /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rrgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
         /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
         background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 10%, white 90%);
         /* Standard syntax */
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: -1; }
         .selectedArea h1 {
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 80px 5px 80px 5px;
         background-size: cover;
         background-position: center;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 28pt;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-weight: 100;
         letter-spacing: 5px;
         color: #1a1a1a;
         opacity: 0;
         transition: all 0.2s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; }
         .selectedArea h1 span {
         background: #fff;
         padding: 10px 80px 10px 80px;
         text-align: center;
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);
         transform: translate(0%, -100%);
         transition: all 0.8s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease; }
         .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn {
         width: 880px;
         float: left;
         position: relative;
         left: 50%;
         margin-left: -450px;
         padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
         margin-top: 15px;
         margin-bottom: 85px;
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 100%);
         transform: translate(0%, 100%);
         transition: all 0.8s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
         transition-delay: 0.2s;
         -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s; }
         .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn p {
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         font-size: 12pt;
         line-height: 24pt;
         letter-spacing: 1px;
         font-weight: 100;
         color: #2a2a2a; }
         .noTransition {
         transition: all 0.0s ease !important;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.0s ease !important;
         transition-delay: 0.0s !important;
         -webkit-transition-delay: 0.0s !important; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
         .projects {
         width: 48%; }
         .projects hr {
         top: 60% !important; }
         .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
         width: 48%; }
         .projects:nth-child(1) hr, .projects:nth-child(2) hr {
         top: 53% !important; }
         .selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn {
         width: 100%;
         margin-left: 0%;
         left: 0%; }
         .selectedArea h1 {
         font-size: 20pt; }
         .selectedArea h1 span {
         padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; } }
         @media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
         .projects {
         width: 98% !important; }
         .projects hr {
         top: 55% !important; }
         .projects:nth-child(1), .projects:nth-child(2) {
         width: 48%; }
         .projects:nth-child(1) hr, .projects:nth-child(2) hr {
         top: 55% !important; } }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Our Brands</h2>
      <div id="projectsApp">
         <div class="projects" :id="project.ID" v-for="project in projects" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + project.bImage + ')' }" v-on:click="selectProjects(project.ID)">
            <h3 class="beforeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h3>
            <div class="info">
               <h1 class="fadeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h1>
               <hr>
            </div>
            <p class="backArrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
         </div>
         <div class="selectedArea">
            <h1 :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + highlightedContent.bImage + ')' }"><span>{{ highlightedContent.category }}</span></h1>
            <div v-html="highlightedContent.copy" class="copyArea fadeIn"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         var isSelected = false;
         const myProjects = [
           {
             ID: "-balmainParis",
             category: "Balmain Paris",
             bImage: "http://twofeetmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/web-designer.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-atkinsonsLondon",
             category: "Atkinsons London",
             bImage:
               "https://i1.wp.com/diymarketers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Graphic-designer-at-work.-Color-samples-000089125041_Small.jpg?fit=800%2C533",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-appellesApothecary",
             category: "Appelles Apothecary",
             bImage:
               "https://agc.creativelive.com/agc/pages/channel-hero/Photo_Hero_1600x900.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-biologySmart",
             category: "Biology Smart Skincare",
             bImage:
               "https://i0.wp.com/webdesignledger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/7-logo-sketches.jpg?w=970",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-soak",
             category: "Soak",
             bImage: "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1644197/images/o-EMAIL-facebook.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-kevinMurphy",
             category: "Kevin Murphy",
             bImage:
               "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-urbanSkincare",
             category: "Urban Skincare Co.",
             bImage:
               "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-zambeli",
             category: "Zambeli",
             bImage:
               "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           },
           {
             ID: "-embrace",
             category: "Embrace",
             bImage:
               "https://appdevelopermagazine.com/images/news_images/Why-Continuos-Delivery-is-Key-for-Success-App-Developer-Magazine_roguohry.jpg",
             copy:
               "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p>"
           }
         ];
         
         var theHighlightedContent = { ID: "", category: "", bImage: "", copy: "" };
         var selectedProject;
         var scrollBackTo;
         
         var app = new Vue({
           el: "#projectsApp",
           data() {
             return {
               projects: myProjects,
               highlightedContent: theHighlightedContent
             };
           },
           methods: {
             selectProjects: function(thisId) {
               var self = "#" + thisId;
               if ($(self).hasClass("openedProject")) {
                 isSelected = false;
         
                 if ($(self).hasClass("noTransition")) {
                   var timeoutA = 0;
                   var timeoutB = 0;
                   var timeoutC = 0;
                 } else {
                   var timeoutA = 800;
                   var timeoutB = 1200;
                   var timeoutC = 1600;
                 }
         
                 $(self).addClass("midTransition");
                 $(self).removeClass("openedProject");
         
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $(self).removeClass("midTransition");
                   $(".selectedArea").removeClass("opened");
                 }, timeoutA);
         
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $("#projectsApp .projects").removeClass("hidden");
                   $("#projectsApp .projects").removeClass("shrunk");
                 }, timeoutB);
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   // window.scrollTo(0, scrollBackTo);
                   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollBackTo }, 500);
                   $(self).addClass("noTransition");
                 }, timeoutC);
               } else {
                 isSelected = true;
                 scrollBackTo = $(self).offset().top;
         
                 if ($(self).hasClass("noTransition")) {
                   $(".selectedArea").addClass("noTransition");
                   $(".copyArea.fadeIn").addClass("noTransition");
                   var timeoutD = 0;
                 } else {
                   $(".selectedArea").removeClass("noTransition");
                   $(".copyArea.fadeIn").removeClass("noTransition");
                   var timeoutD = 800;
                 }
         
                 $(self).addClass("midTransition");
                 $("#projectsApp .projects").addClass("hidden");
                 $(self).removeClass("hidden");
         
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $(".selectedArea").addClass("opened");
                   $(self).addClass("openedProject");
                   $(self).removeClass("midTransition");
                   $("#projectsApp .projects").addClass("shrunk");
         
                   $(self).removeClass("shrunk");
         
                   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                 }, timeoutD);
               }
         
               for (var i = 0; i < this.projects.length; i++) {
                 if (thisId == this.projects[i].ID) {
                   this.highlightedContent = this.projects[i];
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         });
         
         $(document).ready(function() {
           resizeProjectDivs();
           // resizeProjectDivs();
         });
         var resizeTimer;
         $(window).on("resize", function(e) {
           clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
           resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
             if (isSelected == false) {
               resizeProjectDivs();
             }
           }, 250);
         });
         
         function resizeProjectDivs() {
           var midRange = false;
           var smallRange = false;
           var winWidth = $(window).width();
           if (winWidth < 920 && 620 < winWidth) {
             midRange = true;
           }
           if (winWidth < 720) {
             smallRange = true;
           }
           var i = 0;
         
           $("#projectsApp .projects").each(function() {
             var pWidth = $(this).width();
             var pHeight;
             if (i < 2) {
               pHeight = pWidth;
             } else {
               if (midRange == true) {
                 pHeight = pWidth * 0.5;
               } else if (smallRange == true) {
                 pHeight = pWidth;
               } else {
                 pHeight = pWidth * 1.5;
               }
             }
             $(this).css("height", pHeight + "px");
             i++;
           });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I got confused there. Where exactly should i import it and how? I tried adding it after the meta tag, and someone suggested declaring it before the body ends. but both seems to not work. it does work on my codepen account, but not in the localhost file

Comment: @UmaruHime you have to import in you head file,
you just have to create one HTML file than put HTML code from above answer and put css code in style into head tag and put script tag at end of file

Comment: I have already import the file in the head tag. I did it in this format :
`<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Stylish Menu</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: I updated my main question and declared it on the head tag. together with the current output.

Comment: @UmaruHime i update answer for single HTML file. Using this code make one single HTML file it will work.

Comment: This seems to work on my end now. I tried to call out still my css file and it works. I just left the js file on the main html. However, the code is too long. Is it really not possible to call the main.js file outside?

Comment: @UmaruHime yes you can create main.js file and call it to in your html file and also you can create external css file and call it into html file.
If my solution solved your problem than please except my question with right click

Comment: You have my sincerest gratitude.

Comment: @UmaruHime Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change your code:

```
data() {
    return {
       projects: myProjects,
       highlightedContent: theHighlightedContent
    };
},
```

From a function to JSON:

```
data: {
        projects: myProjects,
        highlightedContent: theHighlightedContent
      },
```

Comment: `data` should actually be a function: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: so is this one wrong? i believe it's only due to my placing since the code works on codepen